# Help with solving inequality involving logarithm

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I would like to determine the solutions to the inequality 
$$
\log(1 - x) + 2x > 0.
$$

I'm aware of the approach of using the Lambert W function for solving **equalities** of the form $$e^{x} + ax = b,$$ 
but I'm unsure how to extend this to an **inequality**. 
Wolframalpha tells me that the range of $x$ is $$0<x<1/2 (W(-2/e^2) + 2)$$ but I cannot figure out how to arrive at the upper bound on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
 \log(1-x) + 2x  \ge 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow \log(1-x) + 2(x-1) > -2 \\
 \Longleftrightarrow (1-x)e^{2(x-1)} > e^{-2} \\
 \Longleftrightarrow 2(x-1)e^{2(x-1)} < -2 e^{-2}
$$
Now $y e^y = -2 e^{-2}$ has the two solutions
$y_1 = -2$ and $y_2 =  W(-2 e^{-2})$, and $y e^y < -2 e^{-2}$
exactly if $y_1 < y < y_2$. Therefore we get
$$
 -2 < 2(x-1) < W(-2 e^{-2}) \\
\Longleftrightarrow 0 < x < 1 + \frac 12 W(-2 e^{-2}) \approx 0.7968 \, .
$$